Server ran out of space, is it safe to delete `/tmp/drill`?
My server ran out of space, is it safe to delete /tmp/drill?  Most of the space is taken by the countless *.sys.drill files in /tmp/drill/profiles.

You can check with if any process still writes to those files.
lsof /tmp/drill/profiles/*.sys.drill

If you're unsure if you need these files or not, you can always move them to another partiton.
